# what's the difference between invoke-virtual and invoke-direct in android

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

It said that `invoke-virtual` is invoking the virtual method, while `invoke-direct` is the direct method.

However I'm not clear what is "virtual method" and what is "direct method"?

In other words, what kind of method invoking will be `invoke-virtual` and what kind will be `invoke-direct`?

Can anyone give some concrete example?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html, a direct method is "any of static, private, or constructor".

However, static methods get their own `invoke-static` opcode, so `invoke-direct` is used for constructors and private methods.

Comment: I believe the link should be http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html. Look at `invoke-kind` section.

Comment: Both the old link and new link point to the dex-format.html doc, which contains the quote that I included, in the documentation for the "direct_methods" section. dalvik-bytecode.html also includes similar language in the documentation for invoke-direct.